# Fast webpage loading using the all new "HTML import" draft in 2018: replacing rel="stylesheet" with rel="import"

Tags: html, css, performance, web-services, html-imports

While testing my mobile-friendly page with google page speed analyser it said this:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold
>   content. Your page has 2 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay
>   in rendering your page. None of the above-the-fold content on your
>   page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to
>   load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or
>   inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.

According to this [google page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) and [w3c 2018 March draft](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/#link-type-import) soon the web will support HTML import.:

> Note that the web platform will soon support loading stylesheets in a
>   non-render-blocking manner, without having to resort to using
>   JavaScript, using HTML Imports.

#### My first quesion is:

What are the ways to convert old style stylesheets into HTML import?

Can I simply change...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=etc'/>
```

...into:

```
<link rel="import" type="text/css" href="all.css"/>
<link rel='import' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=etc'/>
```

#### My second question is:

(When) will the web platforms [major browsers like Chrome, Edge, Firefox and major server technologies like php 7.2 on apachee] be ready to safely make the move site wide from `rel="stylesheets"` to `rel="import"`?

#### My third bonus question is:

Aside from a small performance gain according to google, will there (in the future) be any down sites in using HTML import versus the old rel="stylesheet"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply convert a `stylesheet <link>` into an `import <link>` because `<link rel="import">` will load only a HTML document, not a CSS stylesheet.

```
<link rel="import" href="imported-styles.html" async>
```

Therefore, the styles imported via HTML Imports must be included into  elements:

*imported-styles.html*:

```
<style> 
    //content of all.css
    ... 
</style>
```

Alernately use standard `<link rel="stylesheet">`:

*imported-styles.html*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=etc'/>
```

Note that you should use the `async` attribute if you don't want to wait for the imported document to be loaded before processing the rest of the main HTML document.

---

By now [only Chrome and Opera](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=html%20imports) are implementing HTML Imports natively. Other browser vendors don't plan to implement it, so you'll need to use a polyfill with Edge and Firefox.

It's a cient-side technology so the server frameworks are not really concerned.

The downside in using HTML Imports is that, in some special situations, the behaviour could be slightly different with polyfilled implementations (which is true with most polyfills). See the [limitatons](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports#caveats--limitations) of the polyfill.

Comment: Even Chrome is going to remove HTML Import in M73. I don't really figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

HTML Import is actually being deprecated, although it's implemented already in Chrome. So don't use it.

https://dev.to/nektro/the-downfall-of-html-imports-is-upon-us-to-me

A similar feature which is called "HTML Module" will be introduced in the future, but even the standard itself is still being discussed on Github, so it'll take a long long time for us to be able to use it.

https://github.com/dglazkov/webcomponents/blob/html-modules/proposals/HTML-Imports-and-ES-Modules.md

Comment: The link you added suggest that "styling the main document" from HTML Imports is deprecated. HTML Imports module loader itself is not deprected. As of 2018 there are still updates of the editor's draft : https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/

Comment: Yep that link doesn't indicate the deprecation of HTML Import directly. I can't find it immediately right now but here's the potential "next generation HTML Import" proposal: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/645 . As you can see a new proposal is brought up earlier to replace HTML Import.

Comment: What I see now is that Chrome is also going to remove HTML Import in M73. I don't really figure out what's happening

Comment: @Eric what's happening is that the initial HTML Import spec is/was causing lots of problems so some browsers were concerned to implement it. That leads to almost only Chrome has implemented it. So WHATWG decided to deprecated it, take the lesson they learned and come up with something new in the future. As for now, HTML Module is the replacer.

Answer (score 1):

> First question

There is no way by now. HTML Imports are a way to include and reuse HTML documents in other HTML documents, see [HTML Imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/) docs.

> Second question

It's Hard to tell when `rel="import"` will be widely available, but you can easily track browser support on *Can I Use* website https://caniuse.com/#search=import, It also shows if the next version to release will support it.

> Third bonus question

`rel="import"` is to import HTML files.

`rel="stylesheets"` is to import CSS files.

You still need to use `rel="stylesheets"` to load your CSS files.

Comment: Thanks! Please expand on what Google said `"Note that the web platform will soon support loading STYLESHEETS in a non-render-blocking manner, using HTML Imports."` Please implement in your answer HOW TO IMPLEMENT this, since you said rel="import" is NOT for stylesheets. Or do you mean `"It is impossible at the moment"` when you wrote `"There is no way by now."`